# How should I implement a CSS style changer in a PHP CMS?

Tags: php, css, content-management-system

### Background

I'm developing my own OOP content management system in PHP for fun and to expand my programmig knowledge

#### What I've got

I've got the main framework set up, users can login to the backend, add pages, edit pages, set up content in rows or columns, add logo's, billboards, etc.

#### Expantion

My next venture is to allow users to modify the style of their website through the panel. including header colours, font size, font family, etc

#### How to Implement

I thought of a number of ways to do this, but i wanted to ask the community to see if they can come up with a better solution or justify one of my solutions.

#### Idea 1:

I could write/find a php class that parses a css style sheet, and then re-writes it as the new style sheet with the editted values

#### Idea 2:

I could separate the existing style sheet into structure, colors, fonts, etc, and just allow the user to modify the colors and fots separately.

#### Idea 3:

I could ditch the whole separating style from content idea, and make php to write the user specified styles right into the html...

#### Information

Does anybody have any other methods they could think of?

If not which one of mine would work best/be most efficient/optimal etc

This is not a discussion, I'm asking a specific programming question.

I understand that the panel must have an interface for the user to change the values and save their configuration in a Database OR save their configuration directly in the new css file.

I'm just not sure which way would be the "best" way.

How would 'you' do it?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289841/what-is-the-best-most-simple-way-to-implement-a-php-css-style-changer-into-a-cu ?

Comment: Yes its a duplicate, but nobody answered it

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-my-old-unanswered-questions

Answer (score 0):

I would change the stylesheets with JavaScript, like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="somestyle.css" id="stylesheet">

function changeStyle(cssfile) {
  document.getElementById('stylesheet').href = cssfile;
}
```

I also would enter the user's selections via AJAX into the database, so when PHP creates the next page, it knows which styles the user has selected.